# How to capture checked and unchecked events of a checkbox in a listbox.

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I have the below ui (xaml) in my view of mvvm app:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SavedDataSource}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
   <StackPanel >  
        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <TextBlock   Text="{Binding DataSourceCreatedTime}"/>
  </StackPanel >  
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

And I am binding the below source to the above view

```
  private ObservableCollection<DataSource> _SavedDataSource = new ObservableCollection<DataSource>();
    public ObservableCollection<DataSource> SavedDataSource
    {
        get
        {
            ObservableCollection<DataSource> savedDataSource = new ObservableCollection<DataSource>();
            savedDataSource = DataSource.GetSaved();              
            return savedDataSource;
        }
        set
        {
            this._SavedDataSource = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SavedDataSource");
        }
    }
```

the first issue I see is my ischecked event is never fired.

i have below property attached to it.

```
    private bool _IsSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _IsSelected; }
        set { _IsSelected = value; RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected"); }
    }
```

After checked and unchecked events how do I get the Checked and Unchecked item details in the listbox or collection?

Comment: please specify how exactly `IsChecked` event is not fired? Is corresponding property in `DataSource`changed?

Comment: Could you please tell of which classes the C# code snippets are part of? I assume the first is part of your view model class (which is probably bound to the `DataContext` of your view). And the second snippet is part of your `DataSource` class?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a mode of TwoWay on your IsSelected property if you want the UI to update your backing property. For the list box selected item, I would use a TwoWay binding property on the list box - selected item bound to a DataSource property in your data context.

***EDIT***
I see the problem now, the click event is getting eaten by the checkbox and not bubbling to the selected event of the list box.  The work around I came up with was adding a checked event to the checkbox and setting the selected item like so:

```
    private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((AppViewModel)this.Resources["AppViewModel"]).SelectedDataSource = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as DataSource;
    }
```

Comment: I am using twoway mode for isselected property in my viewmodel, but still I don't get the event.when the checkbox is selected by user I want to capture that item details .the selecteditem event works fine but it doesn't fire when the checkbox is checked or unchecked.

Comment: Are you trying to use the actual checked event of the checkbox? If so, can you post the relevant code for how you are setting the checked event in your xaml and viewmodel.